# How to convert xml on java code?

Tags: android

I need to use View to set a divider on my table layout. I can do it in xml but I want is to programmatically created the view.

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />
```

How should i do it. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried ?

```
      View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#aaa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is to create an imageview and settings its layout params and color

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ImageView iv1= new ImageView();
iv1.setLayoutParams(params);
iv1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black); // if you define black as color in xml or any color
```